# Using array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

I'm using a jQuery plugin to build an input mask, but my code is too large.

The user must not be able to start the phone number with zero. The error message has to disappear when he types the right number.

How can I optimize this code? Can I use an array for the numbers? I haven't found a way to do this. Thanks in advance!

```js
var inputMask = function(val) {
  return '(00) 0 0000-0000'
},
noZero = {
  onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
    if (field.val() == "") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(1") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(2") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(3") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(4") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(5") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(6") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(7") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(8") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(9") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (field.val() == "(0") {
      document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "Don't start with zero";
      field.val(field.val().substr(0, 1))
    }
    field.mask(inputMask.apply({}, arguments), options)
  }
};
  
$("input[type='tel']").mask(inputMask, noZero)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="tel">
<div id="PhoneError" style="color:red"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're evaluating all states, both good and bad, instead of just checking for the invalid states of the value.

You can simply clear the error message when a new key is pressed, then check the value for known invalid rules; in this case, beginning with `(0`.

```js
let $phoneError = $('#PhoneError');
let inputMask = function(val) {
  return '(00) 0 0000-0000'
};
let noZero = {
  onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
    $phoneError.text(''); // clear the error when a new key is typed.
    
    // evaluate known invalid states only:
    if (val == "(0") {
      $phoneError.text("Don't start with zero");
      field.val((i, v) => v.substr(0, 1));
    }
    field.mask(inputMask.apply({}, arguments), options)
  }
};
  
$("input[type='tel']").mask(inputMask, noZero)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="tel">
<div id="PhoneError" style="color:red"></div>
```

As an aside to the issue, returning a hard-coded string from a function to set `inputMask` is not necessary. You can just set the string directly:

```
let inputMask = '(00) 0 0000-0000';
```

Comment: Working buddy, thank you!